# imageView.image from Data not displaying

Tags: ios, swift, multipeer-connectivity

I'm trying to display the camera feed of iPhone A on iPhone B. I'm doing this by converting each frame into a Data object, sending it to iPhone B over MultiPeer Connectivity, then converting the data back to a UIImage and displaying it.

After extracting the frame, iPhone A sends it:

```
func sendImageAsData(image: UIImage) {

    if let imageData = image.pngData() {
        print(imageData)
        MultiPeer.instance.send(data: imageData)
    }
}
```

and iPhone B receives it and parses it:

```
func multiPeer(didReceiveData data: Data) {
    print(data)
    let receivedImage = UIImage(data: data)
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.drawView.image = receivedImage
    }
}
```

But all I see on iPhone B's side is a white screen. The output of the console on iPhone B's side prints the number of bytes received, so I know it's at least receiving the data. I've also tried using `image.jpegData(compressionQuality: 1)` to convert the image into Data, but still only saw a white screen.

**EDIT**: I added a `print(receivedImage)` line right after `let receivedImage = UIImage(data: data)` line, and the console output was:

```
138990 bytes
nil
139089 bytes
nil
139085 bytes
nil
139492 bytes
nil
```

So the image isn't displaying because it's `nil`. Any input as to why would be appreciated.

**EDIT 2**: This is the `MultiPeer.instance.send()` function being used to send the data.

```
 public func send(data: Data) -> Bool{
    if isConnected {
        do {
            let item = try NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: data, requiringSecureCoding: true)
            try session.send(item, toPeers: session.connectedPeers, with: MCSessionSendDataMode.reliable)
            return true
        } catch let error {
            printDebug(error.localizedDescription)
            return false
        }
    }
    return false
}
```

Comment: Try **if let imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(yourImage) { ... }**

Comment: @Sateesh I initially did, but Xcode said `'UIImagePNGRepresentation' has been replaced by instance method 'UIImage.pngData()'`

Comment: Are you actually using `MultiPeer.instance.send(object: imageData, type: DataType.image.rawValue)` ?

Comment: @DonMag I updated my question with the `send` function I'm using.

Comment: @JimmyJam - I assume you're using the "MultiPeer" pod? Why not use their default `send(object: Any, type: UInt32)` function?

Comment: @DonMag - It turns out I modified that function for a previous problem I was trying to solve. I'm gonna try MultiPeer's original default function, but this issue makes me not so hopeful it'll work: https://github.com/dingwilson/MultiPeer/issues/15#issuecomment-421633126

Comment: Have you tried their sample app? I gave it a quick try, and was able to send an image from an iPad to an iPhone without problem (both running iOS 10.2.1). Also, I'm using Xcode 9 / Swift 4.1 -- so `UIImagePNGRepresentation` instead of `.pngData()`, but I can't imagine that's causing the issue. Can you successfully send a String?

Comment: And, out of curiosity... In your `sendImageAsData` func... can you successfully convert `imageData` back to a displayable `UIImage`?

Comment: @DonMag - I'm going to also give that sample app a try. I have been able to send Strings, that's actually what I modified the original function for. I've been poking around other SO posts all morning, and a common theme among the accepted answers is that `UIImage(data:)` will return `nil` If an image can't be initialized with the data...I have a feeling that's what's going on here.